# Showing a status message generically within ASP.NET webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Within my site master I have an area where I would like to display status (info, success, error, warning) messages.

In my code behind I would like to make calls such as:

```
MessageSuccess("Some success message");
MessageSuccess("Another success message");
MessageWarning("Warning message");
```

and then have these messages all display when the page is next rendered.

I have tried a couple of approaches where I:

- Save a structure in Session
- Read the structure in Page_PreRender() and update some HTML controls
- Clear the structure in Page_UnLoad()

However some of the time the messages show just fine, but some of the time by the time PreRender comes around Page_Unload() has been called and nothing displayed because the structure is empty.

Has anyone got a generic working solution that I can use with my WebForms project to "nicely" display status messages?

Comment: Try clearing the structure in PreRender, after you've used the values to update your controls.

Answer (score 0):

Once I was using something very close to example described in `Displaying a Custom Error Message` section of the [Working with Partial-Page Rendering Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb398976(v=vs.100).aspx). It works nicely if you are dealing with asynchronous postbacks. The only downside is that it was designed for exception handling and not for success/warning/etc. notifications.

There is a property `AsyncPostBackErrorMessage` on `ScriptManager` which you can use to pass any text message back to the client. Client will retrieve the message in `endRequest` event handler:

Server code:

```
// inside Page code:
var scriptManager = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this /* assuming that this is a Page instance */);
scriptManager.AsyncPostBackErrorMessage = "Hello world";
```

Client code:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);

function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
    if (args.get_error() != undefined) {
       var errorMessage = args.get_error().message;
       args.set_errorHandled(true);

       // Do whatever you need to display the message
    }
}
```

Another possible solution would be to add client function calls to the page using [`ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerstartupscript(v=vs.110).aspx). I can imagine that you can have a `NotificationHandler` JavaScript object which would have a `success`, `warning`, `error`, etc. functions which you will call from the server side:

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "<Some unique key for script>", "NotificationHandler.success(\"Hello world\")", true);
}
```